# Delete labelled partition non interactively with one command

Tags: partition, dd, fdisk, parted

I know about `fdisk` and `parted`, but I was not able to figure out an non interactive way to delete a labelled partition. I imagine something like

```
<command> <action> /dev/disk/by-label/LABEL
```

I also tried to mess around with `dd`, but it ended up being shown as not empty by gparted (it did not recognize the partition).

Whats the correct way of doing this? The aim is to have unpartitioned space in place of the partition.

Comment: You can pipe data into fdisk, eg `echo "m" | fdisk /dev/sda` will print the menu and exit.

Answer (score 2):

You want to delete a partition based on its label ? What if you have two or more partitions with the same label ?

You can delete a partition with `parted` in command line mode (non-interactive) but it won't take partition label as an argument. You have to invoke `parted` with a device name as argument and pass the partition number to `rm` command:

```
parted $device rm $minor
```

e.g. to delete `/dev/sdd2` you would run:

```
parted /dev/sdd rm 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The label is a unique "deleteit" label for sure. Hm, then I would need to figure out a way to get the required data, based on the label.

Comment: `blkid -L deleteit` should give you the name of the partition.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot, though, getting the information and splitting to $device and $minor could be error prone, while deleting exact by disk (/dev/disk/by-label/LABEL) is reliable.

Comment: @GEO - you can run: `lsblk /dev/disk/by-label/MYLABEL -no pkname,name`, that will output the parent device name and partition name, something like `sdd    sdd5`. Now you have the $device and $partition so it's easy to extract $minor (partition number). Alternatively, to get only the partition number you could use: `udevadm info --name=/dev/disk/by-label/DATA | awk -F '=' '/ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER/{print $NF}'`